# Call eventReactive for an arbitrary number of action buttons

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny-server, shiny

What I'm trying to do is create an arbitrary number of action button, each of which has their own event based on their own individual values.

Let's say we want to create a number of buttons. What we do is draw a random number between 1 and 100 and call it *n*. Then we create *n* buttons, each with a value between *1* and *n* (covering every number once). Then, when we press one of those buttons, we render a text message being the number that we pressed.

To set up the buttons, we have:

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
   actionButton('roll','roll'),
   uiOutput('buttons')
))
```

**Server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  n <- eventReactive(input$roll, {
    num <- sample(1:100,1)
    sample(1:num, num, replace=FALSE)
  })

  output$buttons <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:length(n()), function(i) {
      actionButton(as.character(n()[i]), as.character(n()[i]) )
    })
  })

})
```

This generates the buttons. However, I'm struggling to find a way to create all the necessary `eventReactive()`s. I tried calling `eventReactive()` inside a loop, and in a `lapply` call. However, in order to make that loop or `lapply`, you need the value of `length(n())`, which can only be called inside another reactive or observe command.

Given the buttons generated from the above script, how do we make a reactive expression for each button, and then output the text corresponding to the number pressed?

Answer (score 0):

You can search through the input looking for buttons that have been triggered.  Once a button is clicked, its value is greater than 0, so all the picked values will print this way (not sure if that is desired?)

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    shinyUI(fluidPage(
        sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
                actionButton('roll','roll'),
                uiOutput('buttons')
            ),
            mainPanel(
                textOutput('stuff')
            )
        )
    )),
    shinyServer(function(input, output) {

        n <- eventReactive(input$roll, {
            num <- sample(1:100,1)
            sample(1:num, num, replace=FALSE)
        })

        output$buttons <- renderUI({
            lapply(1:length(n()), function(i) {
                actionButton(as.character(n()[i]), as.character(n()[i]) )
            })
        })

        output$stuff <- renderText({
            val <- which(lapply(paste(n()), function(i) input[[i]]) == TRUE)
            if (length(val))
                sprintf("Picked %s!", paste(n())[val])
        })

    })
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to be a reactive event. That is, an event that occurs every time the button is pressed. In your example, I think, the event can only ever occur once. In the actual situation I'm working with, I want the event to be changing the input of another widget (using updateSelectInput inside an observeEvent).